# Why doesn't my Portal 2 map compile using Hammer++? (Possibly a VBSP crash?)

Tags: portal-2, source-engine, hammer

[image: portal 2 compile non-error]

As seen in the screenshot of my compile window, it seems that vbsp.exe runs and then... doesn't. There's no error (at least not one that has anything to do with the problem) and the map compiled fine previously, with none of the very small changes being possible causes for this. It seems like it loads the VMF and then just immediately gives up for no reason at all, and the rest of the entire compile process simply doesn't happen.

Comment: Have you been able to successfully compile maps before with this setup? The configuration of Hammer is extremely finicky, more so because frameworks and paths of Source games have changed without added support for the editor.

Comment: Voting to leave open because [map editor questions are on topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/544/185203)

Comment: @Joachim as stated in the original post:

"the map compiled fine previously"

Comment: @pppery yeah, i mean, if it wasnt on-topic then why would there be a tag available specifically for hammer? so i hope this doesn't get closed.

Comment: @pppery Thanks for the pointer! I knew they have been for a long time, but a quick check showed that some had been closed, so I thought that was the new policy.

Comment: VTC: _official_ map editors are on-topic. Hammer++ is not an official map editor. (I think this might be a good fit for a discussion on [meta] though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This odd behavior is probably caused by a `func_instance` with an input that has an incorrect spelling or other problem. I solved this problem in my map by changing an erroneous input on one of my instances.

The bad input was spelled like: `instance:door_open:trigger`.

Problem solved by changing it to: `instance:door_open:Trigger`. (Notice the capitalization.)

I manually typed it in because Hammer was having a problem not showing the inputs in the dropdown list, and made a mistake as a result.